# Crear dos Métodos nuevos

Tags: c++

¿Cómo puedo crear un método para definir los tipos de Vehículos y otro método para imprimir los tipos de Vehículos?. En el main solamente quiero mandar a llamar esos métodos y al ejecutarlo que en pantalla me muestre esos datos.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "vehiculo.h"
#include <vector>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

using std::vector;   


int main(){

  int Cant = 3;
  Vehiculo *Vector [3];

  //Define los tipos de Vehículos Vehiculos

  Vector[0] = new Vehiculo("Automovil", "Toyota", "Rojo", 100000);
  Vector[1] = new Vehiculo("Motocicleta", "Yamaha", "Negro", 0);
  Vector[2] = new Vehiculo("Automovil", "Mazda", "Azul", 150000);


  //Imprime, muestra en pantalla

  for (int i = 0; i <= Cant; i++) {
      Vector[i]->ImprimirCLI();
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Nomenclatura.

Primero debemos aclarar la nomenclatura, porque si no llamamos a las cosas por el nombre que todas las personas entendemos, entonces seremos incapaces de colaborar.

No parece que tengas claro el significado de **definir**. En C++ existen tres conceptos importantísimos respecto a cómo se crean los objetos:

- *Declarar*: Cuando le dices al compilador que un objeto con un nombre concreto existe, pero sin darle detalles al compilador sobre el objeto, ejemplo:

  ```
  class Vehiculo;
  ```
- *Definir*: Cuando informas al compilador de los detalles de un objeto, si no estaba declarado anteriormente una definición cuenta como declaración, ejemplo:

  ```
  class Vehiculo {
  public:
      Vehiculo() {}
  };
  ```
- *Instanciar*: Cuando se crea un objeto del tipo indicado, para poder instanciar un objeto es necesario que haya sido definido, ejemplo:

  ```
  Vehiculo v;
  ```

---

#### Dudas.

> ¿Cómo puedo crear un método para definir los tipos de Vehículos?

Tu pregunta no tiene ningún sentido. No puedes crear métodos para **definir** nada, las definiciones de objeto se redactan en el código, no se crean en tiempo de ejecución. Seguramente querías preguntar:

> ¿Cómo puedo crear un método para **instanciar** los tipos de Vehículos?

Ya lo tienes, es el constructor de la clase `Vehiculo`. Nos falta conocer la **definición** de tu `Vehiculo`, por lo que desconocemos los detalles de su constructor, pero deduzco que puede parecerse a esto:

```
Vehiculo::Vehiculo(std::string tipo, std::string marca, std::string color, int km);
```

También deduzco que carece de constructor por defecto<sup>1</sup>, lo que te ha "*obligado*" a crear una formación<sup>2</sup> de **punteros** a `Vehiculo` para evitar el problema de no poder construir una formación de **instancias** de `Vehiculo`. Pero si tu formación de `Vehiculo` tiene tamaño fijo, puedes instanciarlos directamente:

```
// INSTANCIA los tipos de Vehículos Vehiculos
Vehiculo Vector[]
{
    {"Automovil",   "Toyota", "Rojo",  100000},
    {"Motocicleta", "Yamaha", "Negro", 0},
    {"Automovil",   "Mazda",  "Azul",  150000}
};
```

Si te fijas hemos dejado el tamaño de la formación vacío, ya que es el compilador quien cuenta los elementos (3).

> ¿Cómo puedo crear un método para imprimir los tipos de Vehículos?

En general suele hacerse mediante la sobrecarga al [operador de inyección de datos de `std::ostream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt), necesitarás **declarar** este operador como amigo de tu clase:

```
class Vehiculo {
    std::string tipo;
    std::string marca;
    std::string color;
    int km;

    friend std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &, const Vehiculo &);

public:
    Vehiculo() {}
};
```

Y después **definirlo**:

```
std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const Vehiculo &v)
{
    return (o << v.tipo << ' ' << v.marca << ' ' << v.color << ' ' << v.km);
}
```

De esta manera podrás mostrar `Vehiculo` por pantalla:

```
Vehiculo v("Ingenio intergaláctico", "Enterprise", "Blanco", 0);
std::cout << v;
```

---

1. Constructor que no recibe ningún parámetro.
2. También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.

Comment: Muchas gracias...