# error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct Punto’

Tags: c

Estoy obteniendo el error de compilación del título: `error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct Punto’`

```
#include <stdio.h>


struct Punto {
   int x;
   int y;
};


int main() {
   Punto = {1,2};
   escalar(punto, 2);
   printf("%i\n", Punto.x);

   return 0;
}

void escalar(Punto p, int num){
   struct Punto *ptr;
   ptr = &p;

   ptr->x += num;
   ptr->y += num;

}
```

Comment: Hola.
Te recomiendo que leas [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para saber como realizar una buena pregunta.

Comment: Tu código tiene muchos errores, pero ninguno de ellos es el que mencionas en la pregunta. Tengo la impresión de que el código que muestras en la pregunta no es realmente el que estás intentando compilar. Quizás quitaste partes para simplificarlo, pero al hacerlo has cambiado demasiadas cosas. Deberías asegurarte de que el código de la pregunta funciona (o mejor dicho, no funciona) como esperas.

Comment: Estoy compilando ese código. Podrías detallar  que errores son?

Comment: `Punto = {1,2};` este es un error, esta variable no tiene nombre.

Comment: Como indica @abulafia, el código contiene muchos errores. Pero ... el indicado **no se puede reproducir**. Voto por cerrarla como `No relacionado`.

Answer (score 3):

El error es claro y conciso, tal vez no lo entiendes por estar en inglés:

> error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct Punto’

Te lo traduzco:

> error: des-referenciando un puntero a un tipo incompleto ‘struct Punto’

El error viene a decir que, el tipo `‘struct Punto’` es incompleto en la línea de código en que estás des-referenciando un puntero a ese tipo, posiblemente aquí:

```
ptr->x += num;
ptr->y += num;
```

Lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/46083/2742) para saber más detalles sobre des-referenciar punteros.

---

Pero ese es el menor de tus problemas, si intento compilar tu código me salen los siguientes errores:

> ```
> In function 'main':
> error: 'Punto' undeclared (first use in this function)
>     Punto = {1,2};
>     ^~~~~
> error: expected expression before '{' token
>     Punto = {1,2};
>             ^
> ```

El primer error indica que el identificador `Punto` no existe. Esto se debe a que en C, `struct` forma parte del tipo así que el identificador `Punto` no existe pero sí existe `struct Punto`.

El segundo error indica que tras la asignación (`=`) no es esperaba una llave (`{`). Esto se debe a que esas llaves están tras un identificador desconocido y no se sabe cómo interpretar la línea, necesitarás estas correcciones:

```
struct Punto punto = {1,2};
```

Tras esas correcciones, encontramos una alarma:

> ```
> In function 'main':
> warning: implicit declaration of function 'escalar' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>     escalar(punto, 2);
>     ^~~~~~~
> ```

Aquí, el compilador está interpretando que la instrucción `escalar(punto, 2)` es una llamada a función (que lo es) pero como la función no ha sido declarada intenta deducir su firma (lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/237472/2742) para saber más sobre declaración de objetos o funciones). La declaración implícita de funciones está deprecada en las versiones más modernas de C, así que este código podría no compilar en otros compiladores y por eso te avisa con una alarma, para arreglarlo pon la definición de `escalar` **antes** de `main`:

```
void escalar(Punto p, int num){
   struct Punto *ptr;
   ptr = &p;

   ptr->x += num;
   ptr->y += num;
}

int main() {
   struct Punto punto = {1,2};
   escalar(punto, 2);
   printf("%i\n", Punto.x);

   return 0;
}
```

Pero ¡esto no resuelve el problema!, los errores que se muestran tras este cambio son:

> ```
> error: unknown type name 'Punto'
>  void escalar(Punto p, int num){
>               ^~~~~
> In function 'main':
> warning: implicit declaration of function 'escalar' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>     escalar(punto, 2);
>     ^~~~~~~
> error: 'Punto' undeclared (first use in this function)
>     printf("%i\n", Punto.x);
>                    ^~~~~
> ```

El primer error es el que ya conocíamos: `struct` forma parte del tipo de datos, por eso no reconoce `Punto` como tipo, esto evita que se pueda interpretar la definición de la función, con lo que vuelve a salir la alarma de declaración implícita de funciones (porque por error, no se pudo declarar explícitamente la función). También encontramos que no reconoce `Punto` como variable, y es normal porque no lo es (es el nombre de la estructura), las últimas correcciones solucionan todos los errores:

```
void escalar(struct Punto p, int num){
//           ~~~~~~ <--- Nuevo
   struct Punto *ptr;
   ptr = &p;

   ptr->x += num;
   ptr->y += num;
}

int main() {
   struct Punto punto = {1,2};
   escalar(punto, 2);
   printf("%i\n", punto.x);
//                ~ <--- Minúscula, no mayúscula

   return 0;
}
```

Aún así el código no parece correcto, ya que quieres que `escalar` modifique el punto recibido, y eso no será posible ya que pasas a dicha función una **copia** de la instancia que quieres modificar, por lo que modificarás la copia y el original permanecerá inalterado. Para evitar esto, debes pasar un puntero:

```
void escalar(struct Punto *p, int num){
//                        ~ <--- Puntero
   p->x += num;
   p->y += num;
}

int main() {
   struct Punto punto = {1,2};
   escalar(&punto, 2);
//         ~ <--- Direccion de punto
   printf("%i\n", punto.x);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: efectivamente quiero que escalar modifique el punto introducido

Answer (score 1):

Básicamente te falta declarar una variable del tipo de la estructura

en un compilador de c++ quedaría así:

```
int main() {
   Punto nombre_variable = {1,2};
   escalar(punto, 2);
   printf("%i\n",nombre_variable.x);

   return 0;
}
```

y en un compilador de c tradicional hay que hacer referencia a la palabra reservada **struct** dando como resultado lo siguiente:

```
int main() {
   struct Punto nombre_variable = {1,2};
   escalar(punto, 2);
   printf("%i\n",nombre_variable.x);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  int x;
  int y;
}Punto;

void escalar(Punto *p, int num);

   int main() {

   int x, y, n;

   printf("Introce coordenada x: \n");
   scanf("%i",&x);
   printf("Introce coordenada y: \n");
   scanf("%i",&y);
   printf("Introce numero a sumar posiciones: \n");
   scanf("%i",&n);

   getchar();

   Punto p = {x,y};
   printf("Punto introducido: (%i,%i)\n",p.x, p.y);

   escalar(&p, n);
   printf("Nuevo Punto: (%i,%i)\n",p.x, p.y);
return 0;

}

void escalar(Punto *p, int num){
    p->x += num;
    p->y += num;

}
```

Comment: SOLUCIONADO !!!